# Can static electricity damage solar cells?

Tags: electrochemistry, photochemistry

How does static electricity damage common solar cells making them less photo reactive? At watt voltage and/or amps would change the chemistry of the common solar cell?

I want to think that as long as the amps are low with a high voltage the static electricity would not change the silicon?

[image]

**____________________________________________________________**
Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35661/could-a-solar-panel-be-modified-to-also-collect-a-static-charge-on-mars

From comments: How they should accumulate that static charge?

This similar to the method I would use to generate static electricity but is not limited to this method. Only the body above the line is important for an answer.

They would accumulate a static charge by moving dust and air past the cells like the blades of this helicopter but with more surface area with less speed.
[image]
https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35587/could-electricty-be-generated-from-a-martian-dust-storm
https://defence.pk/pdf/threads/helicopter-static-electricity-phenomenon.75190/

Comment: How they should accumulate that static charge?

Comment: @Alchimista how does this look?

Comment: My comment was about a standard scenario. The copter blade can't be grounded opposite to a non flying solar cells. In general is hard enough to charge something mounted and composed by a semiconductor cabled by metals. Different if you have a special scenario in mind. It seems more suited for physics or engineering

Comment: @Alchimista the helicopter is grounded during this. I am only interested if high voltage could chemically change the silicon?

Comment: The last is a different question. I don't see how a grounded manufactured consisting of electrical wiring and conductive enough to work as solar cells should accumulate electrostatic charge. If you mean instead if there is a threshold V than certainly yes, but here I mean during solar cell or diode operation.  Move to electrical engineering, I think there is a SE branch.